# Cannot import matplotlib in script

Tags: php, python, matplotlib, import

I am working on a project that involved generating charts of information automatically, as well as other analytical information. In order to accomplish that, I have a set of scripts called automatically from one main script. One of these, generating all the charts, is named `analysis.py`, utilizing the matplotlib library. But for some reason, it is not running.

Here is the beginning of the file where I import matplotlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import convert
from itertools import groupby

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
```

Whenever I run this script manually in the shell, it works just fine:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/Project$ python /var/www/Project/analysis.py
root@ubuntu:/var/www/Project$
```

Also, when I import matplotlib manually it also works fine:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/Project$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
>>>
```

But whenever `analysis.py` is called from whatever locations (PHP script, another python script, etc.) it fails at the import statmenet for matplotlib. It doesn't return any error message (or I don't know how to access them), but I have isolated the error occurs at the import statment for matplotlib by trial and error.

So why doesn't matplotlib import in some situations, and how do I work around it?

**Update:**

I have discovered that calling the script from php and python produces problems for different reasons. From php, I used this script here:

```
$input = 'python /var/www/Project/analysis.py';
$command = escapeshellcmd($input);
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>';
```

This is where the script failed to import the library matplotlib in the `analysis.py`. This is true even when I called `analysis.py` from a different python script (`test.py`), which in turn is called in the php.

But when I run `test.py` directly:

```
import os
command = "python /var/www/Project/analysis.py"
os.system(command)
```

This time the matplotlib imports, but a different problem occurs. Whenever I try to read a particular file, it returns an empty string:

```
with open("/var/www/Project/profile_data.txt") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
next(reader)
```

Because I get this error:

```
next(reader)
StopIteration
```

Which means the file is empty, when it clearly isn't.

Comment: it would be useful to have some small working code as example to reproduce your error. Without that information is almost impossible to say something...

Comment: !/usr/bin/python missing #. It should be #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: The hash is already in there, it just didn't copy over. Edited.

Comment: The first few statements where matplotlib is imported is where the error occurs. The rest of the file is irrelevant (as it is never reached). An example of where I call `analysis.py` automatically is from another python script:

`import os
command = "python /var/www/Project/analysis.py"
os.system(command)`